# Prepend a url to all relative image links in a markdown document

Tags: python, awk, sed, markdown, marko

I have a bunch of markdown documents with a mix of relative and absolute image destinations. e.g.

```
This is some text

![optional caption](/sub/folder/image.png)

And more text

![](https://example.com/cool_image.png)
```

I want to prepend a URL to each of the relative images, e.g. to change the above to

```
This is some text

![optional caption](https://some-image-host/image-host-subpath/sub/folder/image.png)

And more text

![](https://example.com/cool_image.png)
```

but preferably without hard-coding `/sub/folder/` into the replace script (which is how I currently do it).

Is there a clever way to do this with `awk` or `sed` or is that a bad idea due to markdown having more edge cases than one expects?

I made some progress with https://pypi.org/project/marko/, e.g.

```py
import marko
with open("myfile.md") as f: s = f.read()

doc = marko.inline.parser.parse_inline(s)

for i, e in eumerate(doc):
    if type(e) == marko.inline.Image:
        if not e.dest.startswith("http"):
            doc[i].dest = "https://some-image-host/image-host-subpath/" + doc[i].dest
```

which finds all the images and updates the destination of each relative image with the URL, but I'm not quite sure how to render this list of inline elements back into a markdown string again, and I figured I would post here first before re-inventing the wheel in case there is a much simpler way of doing this.

TIA for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command will do it without altering the original file in-place:

```
sed 's_\(^!\[.*\](\)_\1https://some-image-host/image-host-subpath_' <input_file
```

Once you've confirmed it's what you want, you just need to add `-i` after the
`sed` and before the `'s_...` and also remove the `<` before input_file:

```
sed -i 's_\(^!\[.*\](\)_\1https://some-image-host/image-host-subpath_' input_file
```

The way the command works is as follows:

- I'm using `_` as the pattern delimiters instead of the more common `/`,
  because it means I don't have to escape every `/` in the path name.
- This pattern `^!\[.*\](` matches up to where you want to add the path.
- I put the above pattern between the `\(` and the `\)` to remember it for
  later.
- It's added back with `\1`, followed by the path.

A simpler way would have been to simply replace the `](` part of the line with
`])your_url_here`:

```
sed 's_](_](https://some-image-host/image-host-subpath/_' <test
```

but it's possible that the `](` combination might be found on other lines of
your files and so I opted for the stronger test `^!\[.*\](` which only matches
lines beginning with `![` and has some stuff before `](`.

Comment: Perhaps you might want to extend the LHS match to include the `/` of the relative url?

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I think removing the `^` to identify images with `![` is probably ok (and not all our images are at the start of lines, though they probably should be).

Comment: Glad it helped -  you could add some option whitespace at the start with `sed 's_\(^\s*!\[...`